# PDO no such file or directory - only ftp server access

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm moving our php administration to a new server (hosted) but while trying out the migrated system, I detected that our code is unable to access the MySql database. The code was working before and the new webhost says it is supporting PDO. We have no ability to access the actual server more than via ftp and phpmyadmin, preventing us from accessing php.ini. We would prefer to be able to keep using PDO.

1. Any ideas how to fix this, and if not
2. How could we have this file working in the same/a similar way but without PDO?

```php
Class Database{

    protected $_link;

    public function __construct(){
        $config['db'] = array(
            'hostname' => 'localhost', //The provided XXX.loopia.se and 127.0.0.1 has also been attemped here with no result
            'dbname' => 'database_name',
            'username' => 'user_name',
            'password' => 'password'
        );
        $db = new PDO('mysql:hostname=' . $config['db']['hostname'] .';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password']);
        $this->_link = $db;
    }
}
```

Log output:

> PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] No such file or
>   directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock)

Link to loopia's "PHP to SQL"-use-this-code: https://support.loopia.se/files/php_till_mysql.zip

Comment: This might be because of a wrong port. Try passing `;port=/path/to/mysql.sock` with the real path of your provider. And if you don't want to use PDO, use `mysqli`

Comment: See http://7php.com/php-pdo-warning-pdo__construct-pdo-construct-2002-invalid-argument-trying-to-connect-via-unix/ - it may just be like Brewal said, the port `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname:3306;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);`. Google the error message. You will find other links.

Comment: I'm investigating Brewal's answer and Fred's link right now. I have googled the message but all I find is people editing their php.ini files or other local system files, which I cannot access.

Comment: I've made a slight edit to my comment, adding `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname:3306;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);` as an example, in case you may not have seen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quick feedback from the webhost, the above does not seem to be the preffered way to accomplish this at loopia. For further reference for other googlers, this is the code received (and edited to match the above purpose):

```
<?php
Class Database{
protected $_link;
public function __construct(){

$hostname = "xXXX.loopia.se"; //Log on to phpmyadmin and see what it says in the top after "server"
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=<DBNAME>",
    $username, 
    $password, 
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $this->_link = $db;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

}
?>